# jboss 4.2.2 No ClassLoaders found for: org.apache.ws.security.transform.STRTransform

Tags: jboss, alfresco, jboss-4.2.x

So I have a small proof of concept seam app that is based off of one of the Alfresco web client samples. In the process of getting it to work I ran into many problems and stack traces which I was eventually able to fix. Finally my proof of concept works but jboss still logs an error and stack trace. I dont reference STRTransform anywhere so I think the alfresco sdk code does. Below is the full stack trace.

```
10:12:02,676 ERROR [STDERR] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: No ClassLoaders found for: org.apache.ws.security.transform.STRTransform
10:12:02,676 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.mx.loading.LoadMgr3.beginLoadTask(LoadMgr3.java:212)
10:12:02,676 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.mx.loading.RepositoryClassLoader.loadClassImpl(RepositoryClassLoader.java:521)
10:12:02,676 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.mx.loading.RepositoryClassLoader.loadClass(RepositoryClassLoader.java:415)
10:12:02,676 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
10:12:02,676 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
10:12:02,676 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)
10:12:02,676 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.xml.security.transforms.Transform.register(Unknown Source)
10:12:02,676 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.ws.security.WSSConfig.staticInit(WSSConfig.java:310)
10:12:02,676 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.ws.security.WSSConfig.<init>(WSSConfig.java:324)
10:12:02,676 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.ws.security.WSSConfig.getNewInstance(WSSConfig.java:333)
10:12:02,677 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.ws.security.WSSConfig.getDefaultWSConfig(WSSConfig.java:342)
10:12:02,677 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityEngine.getWssConfig(WSSecurityEngine.java:157)
10:12:02,677 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.ws.security.handler.WSHandler.doSenderAction(WSHandler.java:96)
10:12:02,677 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.ws.axis.security.WSDoAllSender.invoke(WSDoAllSender.java:170)
10:12:02,677 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
10:12:02,677 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
10:12:02,677 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
10:12:02,677 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:127)
10:12:02,677 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
10:12:02,677 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
10:12:02,677 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
10:12:02,677 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
10:12:02,677 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
10:12:02,677 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.alfresco.webservice.repository.RepositoryServiceSoapBindingStub.update(RepositoryServiceSoapBindingStub.java:986)
10:12:02,677 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.assistgroup.fileupload.AlfrescoConnector.createNewContent(AlfrescoConnector.java:158)
10:12:02,677 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.assistgroup.fileupload.AlfrescoConnector.addNewContent(AlfrescoConnector.java:81)
10:12:02,677 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.assistgroup.fileupload.UploadHandler.handleUpload(UploadHandler.java:38)
10:12:02,677 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
10:12:02,677 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
10:12:02,677 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
10:12:02,677 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
10:12:02,677 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invoke(Reflections.java:21)
10:12:02,677 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInvocationContext.proceed(RootInvocationContext.java:31)
10:12:02,677 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:56)
10:12:02,677 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.seam.transaction.RollbackInterceptor.aroundInvoke(RollbackInterceptor.java:31)
10:12:02,677 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
10:12:02,677 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.seam.core.BijectionInterceptor.aroundInvoke(BijectionInterceptor.java:46)
10:12:02,677 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
10:12:02,677 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.seam.core.MethodContextInterceptor.aroundInvoke(MethodContextInterceptor.java:42)
10:12:02,677 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
10:12:02,677 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInterceptor.invoke(RootInterceptor.java:107)
10:12:02,677 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.seam.intercept.JavaBeanInterceptor.interceptInvocation(JavaBeanInterceptor.java:166)
10:12:02,677 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.seam.intercept.JavaBeanInterceptor.invoke(JavaBeanInterceptor.java:102)
10:12:02,677 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.assistgroup.fileupload.UploadHandler_$$_javassist_1.handleUpload(UploadHandler_$$_javassist_1.java)
10:12:02,677 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
10:12:02,677 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
10:12:02,677 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
10:12:02,678 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
10:12:02,678 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:329)
10:12:02,678 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:342)
10:12:02,678 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.el.parser.AstPropertySuffix.invoke(AstPropertySuffix.java:58)
10:12:02,678 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:96)
10:12:02,678 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:276)
10:12:02,678 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:68)
10:12:02,678 ERROR [STDERR]     at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:77)
10:12:02,678 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:91)
10:12:02,678 ERROR [STDERR]     at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:383)
10:12:02,678 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processEvents(AjaxViewRoot.java:184)
10:12:02,678 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.broadcastEvents(AjaxViewRoot.java:162)
10:12:02,678 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processApplication(AjaxViewRoot.java:350)
10:12:02,678 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:97)
10:12:02,678 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:251)
10:12:02,678 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:117)
10:12:02,679 ERROR [STDERR]     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:244)
10:12:02,679 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
10:12:02,679 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
10:12:02,680 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:83)
10:12:02,680 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.seam.web.MultipartFilter.doFilter(MultipartFilter.java:80)
10:12:02,680 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
10:12:02,680 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:64)
10:12:02,680 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
10:12:02,680 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.seam.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:45)
10:12:02,680 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
10:12:02,680 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:141)
10:12:02,680 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:281)
10:12:02,680 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.seam.web.Ajax4jsfFilter.doFilter(Ajax4jsfFilter.java:60)
10:12:02,680 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
10:12:02,680 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.seam.web.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:58)
10:12:02,680 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
10:12:02,680 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:158)
10:12:02,680 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
10:12:02,680 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
10:12:02,680 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
10:12:02,680 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
10:12:02,680 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
10:12:02,680 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
10:12:02,680 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
10:12:02,680 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:179)
10:12:02,680 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:432)
10:12:02,680 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
10:12:02,680 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
10:12:02,680 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
10:12:02,680 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
10:12:02,680 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
10:12:02,680 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:262)
10:12:02,680 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
10:12:02,680 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
10:12:02,680 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:446)
10:12:02,680 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
```

contents of: jboss-4.2.2.GA/server/default/lib

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james   58225 2007-10-22 11:45 activation.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james  355304 2007-10-22 11:45 antlr.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james    4942 2007-10-22 11:45 autonumber-plugin.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james  513244 2007-10-22 11:45 bcel.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james   21291 2007-10-22 11:45 bindingservice-plugin.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james  167691 2007-10-22 11:45 bsf.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james   12130 2007-10-22 11:45 bsh-deployer.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james  235510 2007-10-22 11:45 bsh.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james  328602 2007-10-22 11:45 cglib.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james   47469 2007-10-22 11:45 commons-codec.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james  558376 2007-10-22 11:45 commons-collections.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james  214796 2007-10-22 11:45 commons-httpclient.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james   55424 2007-10-22 11:45 commons-logging.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james  313128 2007-10-22 11:45 dom4j.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james   52220 2007-10-22 11:45 ejb3-persistence.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james   28338 2007-10-22 11:45 el-api.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james 2276092 2007-10-22 11:45 hibernate3.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james  444506 2007-10-22 11:45 hibernate-annotations.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james  111590 2007-10-22 11:45 hibernate-entitymanager.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james  643806 2011-06-24 15:36 hsqldb.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james    8739 2007-10-22 11:45 hsqldb-plugin.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james  547559 2007-10-22 11:45 javassist.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james  226484 2007-10-22 11:45 jaxen.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james  723098 2007-10-22 11:45 jboss-cache-jdk50.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james   80470 2007-10-22 11:45 jboss-common-jdbc-wrapper.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james   20384 2007-10-22 11:45 jboss-ejb3x.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james   14182 2007-10-22 11:45 jboss-hibernate.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james  423706 2007-10-22 11:45 jboss-j2ee.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james 2124287 2007-10-22 11:45 jboss.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james   29382 2011-07-01 14:49 jboss-jaxrpc.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james   63828 2011-07-01 14:49 jboss-jaxws.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james  199159 2007-10-22 11:45 jboss-jca.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james   14218 2007-10-22 11:45 jboss-jsr77.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james   65044 2007-10-22 11:45 jboss-jsr88.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james   28372 2007-10-22 11:45 jbossjta-integration.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james  547885 2007-10-22 11:45 jbossjta.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james  152258 2007-10-22 11:45 jboss-management.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james   56301 2007-10-22 11:45 jboss-monitoring.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james  537121 2007-10-22 11:45 jbossmq.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james    8376 2007-10-22 11:45 jboss-remoting-int.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james  863878 2007-10-22 11:45 jboss-remoting.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james   26736 2007-10-22 11:45 jboss-saaj.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james  125849 2007-10-22 11:45 jboss-serialization.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james   46960 2007-10-22 11:45 jboss-srp.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james  312961 2007-10-22 11:45 jbosssx.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james   53279 2007-10-22 11:45 jboss-transaction.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james   65245 2007-10-22 11:45 jbossts-common.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james  121073 2007-10-22 11:45 jboss-vfs.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james   52561 2007-10-22 11:45 jbossws-common.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james   66978 2007-10-22 11:45 jbossws-framework.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james   76820 2007-10-22 11:45 jbossws-jboss42.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james   94561 2007-10-22 11:45 jbossws-spi.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james   33300 2007-10-22 11:45 jmx-adaptor-plugin.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james   48897 2007-10-22 11:45 jnpserver.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james   82156 2007-10-22 11:45 joesnmp.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james    3522 2007-10-22 11:45 jpl-pattern.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james   16995 2007-10-22 11:45 jpl-util.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james   82183 2007-10-22 11:45 jsp-api.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james  355753 2007-10-22 11:45 log4j.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james   15143 2007-10-22 11:45 log4j-snmp-appender.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james  387690 2007-10-22 11:45 mail.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james    5466 2007-10-22 11:45 mail-plugin.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james  767492 2011-01-26 11:58 mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james    8818 2007-10-22 11:45 properties-plugin.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james  390557 2007-10-22 11:45 quartz.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james    3537 2007-10-22 11:45 scheduler-plugin-example.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james   46036 2007-10-22 11:45 scheduler-plugin.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james   89678 2007-10-22 11:45 servlet-api.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james    2657 2007-10-22 11:45 xmlentitymgr.jar
```

Contents of: jboss-4.2.2.GA/lib

```
james@jamesp:~/jboss-4.2.2.GA/lib$ ls -lR
.:
total 2612
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james  47469 2007-10-22 11:44 commons-codec.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james 214796 2007-10-22 11:44 commons-httpclient.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james  55424 2007-10-22 11:44 commons-logging.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james 255425 2007-10-22 11:44 concurrent.jar
drwxr-xr-x 2 james james   4096 2007-10-22 11:44 endorsed
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james  15858 2007-10-22 11:44 getopt.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james 406564 2007-10-22 11:44 jboss-common.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james 880300 2007-10-22 11:44 jboss-jmx.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james 267066 2007-10-22 11:44 jboss-system.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james 377239 2007-10-22 11:44 jboss-xml-binding.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james 128404 2007-10-22 11:44 log4j-boot.jar

./endorsed:
total 3036
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james  188996 2007-10-22 11:44 serializer.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james 1713712 2007-10-22 11:44 xalan.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james 1200039 2007-10-22 11:44 xercesImpl.jar
```

Contents of: my projects ear/lib

```
alfresco-web-service-client-3.2.jar
antlr-runtime.jar
axis.jar
commons-beanutils.jar
commons-collections.jar
commons-digester.jar
commons-discovery-0.5.jar
commons-httpclient.jar
commons-lang.jar
commons-logging.jar
core.jar
drools-compiler.jar
drools-core.jar
janino.jar
jboss-el.jar
jbpm-jpdl.jar
mvel14.jar
richfaces-api.jar
wsdl4j-1.5.1.jar
wss4j-1.5.11.jar
```

While googling I have not found anything so I figured I would post here to see if any one has run into this in the past. If I figure it out I will post back here. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me from your stacktrace that you're calling a part of Alfresco that depends on Apache AXIS (to handle the SOAP stuff), but that you're missing one of the AXIS dependencies. AXIS is trying to do some web service security operation, but is failing because it can't find a required class for that.

A quick google indicates that xmlsec is the jar you're missing. One ships with Alfresco, but you don't appear to have it in your jar listings above, I'd suggest you try adding it and see if that does the trick.

Comment: I will try that, however my version of alfresco did not come with that. I downloaded the 3.4 war version of alfresco, maybe its included with the other download/install methods.

Comment: Ah, it was included with the alfresco sdk under "alfresco-community-sdk-3.4.d/lib/server/dependencies". I put that into the class path and the exception is gone. Thanks Gagravarr